# Understanding the Difference Between 'Initiate' and 'Begin' in English Usage

Tags: transatlantic-differences

Recently, I've been trying to understand the distinction between "initiate" and "begin." Both words seem to refer to the start of something, but I sense that they are used in different contexts and might convey slightly different meanings.

Could someone explain:

1. The primary differences in meaning between "initiate" and "begin."
2. Specific contexts or situations where one word is preferred over the other.

Comment: I wrote ""Initiate" is considerably more formal than "begin". It is used in the sense of "begin a process", or "cause a process to begin""  but I realised that I was just copying the dictionary. https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/initiate

Comment: If in doubt, use begin. It's 10x more common than initiate.  https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=begin%2C+initiate&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3

Comment: Here's an image: In traditional marriages around the world, the husband *initiated* intimacy by *beginning* the back-and-forth exchange.

Comment: This reminded me of the old, old radio show, Listen With Mother. "Are we ready children? …Then let us initiate." …ermmm…not really ;)